# Empty or null values in an HTML table using a JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, google-sheets

I'm building an HTML table that pulls data from Google Sheets using a JavaScript code that I found here in Stack Overflow, and it works fine. My problem: I don't want to print the rows that have empty or null values. I don't have experience with JS and don't know how to do it. In C I would create an array to store the values of the current row and compare if they are valid or not. Is this a good idea in JS? Thank you, I'm a beginner !!

The code: https://codepen.io/mikesteelson/pen/wvevppe (Credit: Mike Steelson)

```
var id = '1n-rjSYb63Z2jySS3-M0BQ78vu8DTPOjG-SZM4i8IxXI';
var gid = '0';
var url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/'+id+'/gviz/tq?tqx=out:json&tq&gid='+gid;
fetch(url)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(data => document.getElementById("json").innerHTML=myItems(data.slice(47, -2))  
  );
function myItems(jsonString){
  var json = JSON.parse(jsonString);
  var table = '<table><tr>'
  json.table.cols.forEach(colonne => table += '<th>' + colonne.label + '</th>')
  table += '</tr>'
  json.table.rows.forEach(ligne => {
    table += '<tr>'
    ligne.c.forEach(cellule => {
        try{var valeur = cellule.f ? cellule.f : cellule.v}
        catch(e){var valeur = ''}
        table += '<td>' + valeur + '</td>'
      }
    )
    table += '</tr>'
    }
  )
  table += '</table>'
  return table
}
```

I tried to solve it by myself, but it didn't work.

Comment: this code is copied from codepen link, can you show us what did you try?

Comment: I tried to use pieces of code that i found here to compare ==0 and ==null in JS, after the try..catch. But it didn't work. I made a simple if too, but nothing changed.

Comment: When you are adding a `<tr>`, check the current `table.row` aka `ligne` and run an `Array.prototype.some` on `ligne.c` and return the value of `cellule.f/cellule.v`. If all the values are empty strings, then do not render the `<tr>`. Essentially you need to iterate through the column values for each row and build a value array. Once you have all the row values, then you can determine if you can append a `<tr>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should build an array of values for the current row and check if there is at least 1 non-empty value in order to render the `<tr>`.

```js
function myItems(jsonString) {
  var json = JSON.parse(jsonString);
  var table = '<table><tr>'
  json.table.cols.forEach(colonne => table += '<th>' + colonne.label + '</th>')
  table += '</tr>'
  json.table.rows.forEach(ligne => {
    // Build value array
    var rowData = [];
    ligne.c.forEach(cellule => {
      var valeur;     
      try {
        valeur = cellule.f ? cellule.f : cellule.v
      } catch (e) {
        valeur = ''
      }
      rowData.push(valeur);
    });
    // Determine if the row is render-able
    if (rowData.length && rowData.some(valeur => valeur)) {
      table += '<tr>'
      rowData.forEach(valeur => {
        table += '<td>' + valeur + '</td>'
      });
      table += '</tr>'
    }
  })
  table += '</table>'
  return table
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!! Saved me! To work, I had to change de condition inside the if

... if (!rowData.includes('', null) && rowData.some(valeur => valeur))